Automatic screen lock not working?
This problem turned up weeks ago, under Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. I can lock my screen with Super+L, but this doesn't occur after the timeout specified in the privacy settings.
After an upgrade to 24.04.1, the problem persists.
